# SharePoint dialogue box/popup crashes Internet Explorer

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, internet-explorer

I used to browse SharePoint Server 2013 site from Internet Explorer 10 installed on my Windows 7 machine. Earlier I did not have any problem with SharePoint site but now my I.E. frequently crashes when a pop up or dialogue box appears such as when I view a list item properties or when I view document version. I believe I.E. in my machine is the culprit behind this rather than the SharePoint, as I don't see this error in my colleagues' I.E.

These are the efforts I hopefully attempted with no avail:

1. Cleared browser history, caches, passwords and temp data.
2. Disabled all add-ons and opened SharePoint site in I.E. (No Add-ons)
3. Used software rendering instead of GPU rendering and rebooted computer.
4. Installed Latest Windows Update.
5. Updated I.E 10 to I.E 11
6. Tried another user account in my computer
7. Did I.E. reset to its default condition and rebooted
8. Used a [Microsoft's Fix Utility](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9646978)

Is there anything I can do before I request for a help desk ticket with System Administrators in my office.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I decided to give one more search for the solution before I really ask for help ticket. Luckily I found something [here](http://sympmarc.com/2013/11/29/fix-internet-explorer-crashes-with-sharepoint-2013-online-presence-indicators/) that exactly match with my scenario. After reading through it I also realized that my I.E. crashes as soon as I hover through a ***User Online Presence Control***.

I did have Office 2013 installed on my computer. As the blog suggests I **repaired my Office 2013** installation and Viola! The battle with I.E. is over.